# AID of JCOP's Security Domain and meaning of "Card Not Fused" or "Not Pre-Personalized"

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I download a software named *JCOP Manger* from [here](http://www.infintuary.org/jcop.php) to deal with my **CJ3A080** jcop java card.

It recognize my card currectly. but it don't let my to install or list applets! why?

Output of this software:

[image]

I try to select the ISD using *CardTool* (The software that I use to send APDU to card), but as you see below none of common AIDs not found on the card :

Note that, *CardTool* output format is as below :

```
< CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Lc | Le
< Command Data Field (If Possible)
> Response Data Field (If Possible)
> SW1 SW2
```

So, This is output of *CardTool* :

```
Answer-to-Reset
3B  F8  13  00  00  81  31  FE  45  4A  43  4F  50  76  32  34  31  B7  

< 00 A4 04 00 08 00
< A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
> 6A82


< 00 A4 04 00 07 00
< A0 00 00 00 03 00 00
> 6A82

< 00 A4 04 00 08 00
< A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00
> 6A82

< 00 A4 04 00 08 00
< A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00
> 6A82

< 00 A4 04 00 07 00
< A0 00 00 00 03 53 50
> 6A82
```

I also try **gp.exe** tool, and this is its output :

```
E:\GP>gp -list
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No selected ISD!
        at openkms.gp.GlobalPlatform.openSecureChannel(GlobalPlatform.java:327)
        at openkms.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:280)

E:\GP>
```

The questions are:

- 1- What does this mean? "**Not Fused (Not Pre-Personalized)**"
- 2- How I can personalize it?
- 3- How we can find that if a card fused or not?
- 4- What is the AID of Security Domain?

**I asked all these 4 questions in a singe topic, because these are closely related to each other**

Comment: Interesting, can you indicate how you received the unfused cards?

Comment: @owlstead One of my friends works in a company that assembling NXP chip in PVC cards. Do you know how I can personalize it? and for god, dear owlstead take a look at those two comments below my another question, please :D ,I am such a deer in the swamp now ;) thansk good man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a smart card can be used, it needs to be "pre-personalized": some basic settings need to be written, ISD keys initialized, etc. If a card is not pre-personalized, it will not respond to normal APDUs.
The pre-personalization process is vendor-specific and there is a chain of trust involved, so you will need to ask your card supplier for the tools, keys and documentation so you can do it.

This blog post http://colinoflynn.com/tiki-view_blog_post.php?postId=34 explains how to know if a JCOP card has been pre-personalized, by sending a SELECT APDU to a special AID. It is probably the same command the JCOP Manager tool you used for your screenshot is sending.

Comment: In fact jcop card will respond on normal APDUs to your applets even if the card is not fused/prepersonalized. However, it is HIGHLY recommended to fuse the card before using it outside development environment

Comment: But a prepersonalized card always responds with 6A82 to all SELECT commands, even the empty one, so there is not much you can do. Or do you mean performing the prepersonalization process, except the final step (fusing the card)?