# List applets on JCOP Cards using GPShell

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform, jcop

I have a JCOP smart card (**CJ3A080**). I wanted to list default applets on the card, so I download last version of GPShell (1.4.4) and run the script named `listjcop10.txt`. But it failed. This is contets of the script :

**listjcop10.txt :**

```
mode_211
gemXpressoPro
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -readerNumber 3
select -AID a000000003000000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
get_status -element 10
#20
card_disconnect
release_context
```

**And this is output of GPShell :**

```
D:\GPShell-1.4.4>gpshell listJCOP10.txt
mode_211
gemXpressoPro
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect -readerNumber 3
Could not connect to reader number 3

D:\GPShell-1.4.4>
```

Does anyone know what is the origin of the problem?

Note that this card is the same card that I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076532/the-meaning-of-card-not-fused)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to connect to the 3rd reader of your system. So, If you have just one card reader connected to the system just use

```
card_connect
```

instead of

```
card_connect -readerNumber 3
```

Comment: Oops! It's really obvious! I think I am stupid :D Thank you Hana.