# What is JCOP Identify Applet for?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I have a **CJ3A080 v2.4.1 NXP JCOP** Smart card.

When I want to select AID=`A0 00 00 01 67 41 30 00 FF`, I receive SW1-SW2=6A82 (File or Application Not Found) and some other data as below :

```
< 00 A4 04 00 09 00
< A0 00 00 01 67 41 30 00 FF
> 02 21 00 33 00 00 00 00 4E 58 30 31 31 43 00 03 ED 10 3C
> 6A82
```

I searched for this `AID` in google, and I found that this is AID of an applet named *JCOP Identify Applet* and this applet is not SELECTABLE.

My questions:

1. What does that data mean?
2. What is thise applets for? When and how I can use it?
3. Is it possible to make it *SELECTABLE*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer in order:

1. see the JCOP admin or user manual (this is information that is usually protected by non-disclosure agreements)
2. to identify the product
3. no

Comment: Did you mean putting this data here make any risk for my card?

Comment: Does the data specific for each card? I mean, can't we identity the product with its ATR?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the JCOP user/admin manual. where I can find it?

Comment: From the person that sold you the cards, or from NXP of course.

Comment: Thank you Mr Owlstead. Would you please check my first and second comments also?

Comment: Excuse me Mr Owlstead, Why they assign an applet for identify the product instead of mentioning those data in Datasheet?

Comment: It's not an Applet. It's just a small part of the runtime that can be used for tracking and identifying a product.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076532/aid-of-jcops-security-domain-and-meaning-of-card-not-fused-or-not-pre-person) in which the Jcop Manager lists Identification data,
This is done by this applet,

I strongly advise you to use Jcop shell in eclipse in order to have an easier interface, 
For this you can use `/identify` there, and the result would be something like this:

```
/identify
 => 00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 01 67 41 30 00 FF          .........gA0..
 (28350 usec)
 <= B3 11 01 29 00 00 00 00 50 48 36 35 30 41 01 03    ...)....PH650A..
    C1 3C 82 6A 82                                     .<.j.
Status: File not found
FABKEY ID:   0xB3
PATCH ID:    0x11
TARGET ID:   0x01 (smartmx)
MASK ID:     0x29 (41)
CUSTOM MASK: 00000000
MASK NAME:   PH650A
FUSE STATE:  fused
ROM INFO:    C13C82
COMBO NAME:  smartmx-m29.B3.11-PH650A
```

Comment: Thank you. Where I can find the meaning of these items? (FABKEY ID, PATCH ID, ...) And also the meaning of different values for them? I mean, What values FABKEY may accept? (for example)

Comment: It's exactly what owlstead said, 'see the JCOP admin or user manual '. you can ask for this document from one you bought the card

Comment: Oh, I noticed something, what is the `00` after `09` in your select command? Is it automatically posted as the response length or this is written by your own? what shell did you use to send this command? and why the select command is written in 2 line? you put `09` as the data length, but the data length is more than that. would you please test the exact command I posted in my response, I mean send `00 A4 04 00 09 A0 00 00 01 67 41 30 00 FF  `

Comment: And please be sure that your card is a Jcop card, cause if it won't you'll get the 0x6A 82 error

Comment: the `00` after `09` is the `Le` (As I mentioned in my another question this is the form that my Development Kit use : `CLA | INS | P1 | P2 | Lc | Le` in first line + `Data` in second line . So I sent the right command). and about the card type, yes! I'm sure. the AID that I mentioned in the question is the AID of **JCOP identity Applet**. and If you search for it, you will find some websites that  indicate it as a jcop cards applet that returns `some data|6A82` in response of SELECT command.

Comment: My software is **CardTool**. It is ACR38 reader's Software Dev Kit.

Comment: May I ask you take a look at my last comment below Mr Owlstead answer?

Comment: Dear Hana, Both answers was good, but I check mr owlasted answer because there answered question 2 and 3 also. your answers helped me to understand the meaning of  that response-data. thank you.