# Why I can't select MF?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

I have a JCOP card (CJ3A080). This is output of *OpenSC-Tool* `list files` command :

```
C:\>opensc-tool -a -c jcop -f -v
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Connecting to card in reader ACS CCID USB Reader 0...
Using card driver JCOP cards with BlueZ PKCS#15 applet.
Card ATR:
3B F8 13 00 00 81 31 FE 45 4A 43 4F 50 76 32 34 ;.....1.EJCOPv24
31 B7                                           1.
3f00 type: DF, size: 0
select[NONE] lock[NEVR] delete[NEVR] create[NEVR] rehab[N/A] inval[N/A] list[NON
E]

  3f002f00 type: wEF, ef structure: transparent, size: 128
  read[NONE] update[NEVR] erase[NEVR] write[NEVR] rehab[N/A] inval[N/A]

00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................
00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................

C:\>
```

Question 1: What is these zero bytes? Is it the EEPROM? if so, why it is just 128 Byte (While my card has a 80KB EEPROM)?

Question 2: What is the meaning of the elements in the below line?

```
select[NONE] lock[NEVR] delete[NEVR] create[NEVR] rehab[N/A] inval[N/A] list[NON
E]
```

Question 2: As I understand from the output, There must be a DF with `3F00` as its AID, right? So why I can't SELECT it?

```
C:\>opensc-tool -s 00a40400023f00
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 02 3F 00
Received (SW1=0x6A, SW2=0x82)

C:\>
```

**Note that I think this is a Un-Fused Card(Not Personalized) --> Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076532/aid-of-jcops-security-domain-and-meaning-of-card-not-fused-or-not-pre-person)**

**Update 1:**

I tested some other different cards (Even some memory cards) with the same above commands. Output is the same above output and just ATR changed! It this output correct and reliable?

**Update 2:**

When I list installed drivers, this is output :

```
C:\>opensc-tool -D
Configured card drivers:
  cardos           Siemens CardOS
  flex             Schlumberger Multiflex/Cryptoflex
  cyberflex        Schlumberger Cyberflex
  gpk              Gemplus GPK
  gemsafeV1        driver for the Gemplus GemSAFE V1 applet
  miocos           MioCOS 1.1
  mcrd             MICARDO 2.1 / EstEID 1.0 - 3.0
  asepcos          Athena ASEPCOS
  starcos          STARCOS SPK 2.3/2.4
  tcos             TCOS 3.0
  openpgp          OpenPGP card
  jcop             JCOP cards with BlueZ PKCS#15 applet
  oberthur         Oberthur AuthentIC.v2/CosmopolIC.v4
  authentic        Oberthur AuthentIC v3.1
  iasecc           IAS-ECC
  belpic           Belpic cards
  ias              IAS
  incrypto34       Incard Incripto34
  acos5            ACS ACOS5 card
  akis             TUBITAK UEKAE AKIS
  entersafe        entersafe
  epass2003        epass2003
  rutoken          Rutoken driver
  rutoken_ecp      Rutoken ECP driver
  westcos          WESTCOS compatible cards
  myeid            MyEID cards with PKCS#15 applet
  sc-hsm           SmartCard-HSM
  setcos           Setec cards
  muscle           MuscleApplet
  atrust-acos      A-Trust ACOS cards
  piv              PIV-II  for multiple cards
  itacns           Italian CNS
  javacard         JavaCard (without supported applet)
  default          Default driver for unknown cards

C:\>
```

My card is a JCOP card. And I can see JCOP in the above list. But when I use `-n` parameter It response with Unsupported Card!

```
C:\>opensc-tool -n
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Unsupported card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this card is not supported by OpenSC

Check the [SupportedHardware](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/SupportedHardware) list. Verify it with `opensc-tool --name` to see if some driver knows how to handle your card.

The expected result of the command is a line with a card driver name.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I update the question. While JCOP is in the installed list, We see it returns Unsupported Card for my NXP JCOP CJ3A080 card. Why? Again because it is Un-Fused? Or I must install a new driver? if so, how?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/JavaCard). It'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line like this:

```
force_card_driver = jcop;
```

in your configuration file (opensc.conf)?